# Keras Neural Network accuracy only 10%

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, conv-neural-network, mnist

I am learning how to train a keras neural network on the MNIST dataset. However, when I run this code, I get only 10% accuracy after 10 epochs of training.  This means that the neural network is predicting only one class, since  there are 10 classes.  I am sure it is a bug in data preparation rather than a problem with the network architecture, because I got the architecture off of a tutorial ([medium tutorial](https://towardsdatascience.com/image-classification-in-10-minutes-with-mnist-dataset-54c35b77a38d)). Any idea why the model is not training?

My code:

```
from skimage import io
import numpy as np
from numpy import array
from PIL import Image
import csv
import random
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
import pandas as pd
from keras.utils import multi_gpu_model
import tensorflow as tf
train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator()
train_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(
    directory="./trainingSet",
    class_mode="categorical",
    target_size=(50, 50),
    color_mode="rgb",
    batch_size=1,
    shuffle=True,
    seed=42
)
print(str(train_generator.class_indices) + " class indices")
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers.core import Dense, Dropout, Activation, Flatten
from keras.layers.convolutional import Conv2D
from keras.layers.pooling import MaxPooling2D, GlobalAveragePooling2D
from keras.optimizers import SGD
from keras import backend as K
from keras.layers import Input
from keras.models import Model
import keras
from keras.layers.normalization import BatchNormalization

K.clear_session()
K.set_image_dim_ordering('tf')
reg = keras.regularizers.l1_l2(1e-5, 0.0)
def conv_layer(channels, kernel_size, input):
    output = Conv2D(channels, kernel_size, padding='same',kernel_regularizer=reg)(input)
    output = BatchNormalization()(output)
    output = Activation('relu')(output)
    output = Dropout(0)(output)
    return output

model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(28, kernel_size=(3,3), input_shape=(50, 50, 3)))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
model.add(Flatten()) # Flattening the 2D arrays for fully connected layers
model.add(Dense(128, activation=tf.nn.relu))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(Dense(10, activation=tf.nn.softmax))


from keras.optimizers import Adam
import tensorflow as tf

model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',
              optimizer='adam',
              metrics=['accuracy'])
from keras.callbacks import ModelCheckpoint

epochs = 10

checkpoint = ModelCheckpoint('mnist.h5', save_best_only=True)

STEP_SIZE_TRAIN=train_generator.n/train_generator.batch_size
model.fit_generator(generator=train_generator,
                    steps_per_epoch=STEP_SIZE_TRAIN,
                    epochs=epochs,
                    callbacks=[checkpoint]
)
```

The output I am getting is as follows:

```
Using TensorFlow backend.
Found 42000 images belonging to 10 classes.
{'0': 0, '1': 1, '2': 2, '3': 3, '4': 4, '5': 5, '6': 6, '7': 7, '8': 8, '9': 9} class indices
Epoch 1/10
42000/42000 [==============================] - 174s 4ms/step - loss: 14.4503 - acc: 0.1035
/home/ec2-user/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow_p36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/callbacks.py:434: RuntimeWarning: Can save best model only with val_loss available, skipping.
  'skipping.' % (self.monitor), RuntimeWarning)
Epoch 2/10
42000/42000 [==============================] - 169s 4ms/step - loss: 14.4487 - acc: 0.1036
Epoch 3/10
42000/42000 [==============================] - 169s 4ms/step - loss: 14.4483 - acc: 0.1036
Epoch 4/10
42000/42000 [==============================] - 168s 4ms/step - loss: 14.4483 - acc: 0.1036
Epoch 5/10
42000/42000 [==============================] - 169s 4ms/step - loss: 14.4483 - acc: 0.1036
Epoch 6/10
42000/42000 [==============================] - 168s 4ms/step - loss: 14.4483 - acc: 0.1036
Epoch 7/10
42000/42000 [==============================] - 168s 4ms/step - loss: 14.4483 - acc: 0.1036
Epoch 8/10
42000/42000 [==============================] - 168s 4ms/step - loss: 14.4483 - acc: 0.1036
Epoch 9/10
42000/42000 [==============================] - 168s 4ms/step - loss: 14.4480 - acc: 0.1036
Epoch 10/10
 5444/42000 [==>...........................] - ETA: 2:26 - loss: 14.3979 - acc: 0.1067
```

The trainingSet directory contains a folder for each 1-9 digit with the images inside the folders. I am training on an AWS EC2 p3.2xlarge instance with the Amazon Deep Learning Linux AMI.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the list of some weird points that I see :

- Not rescaling your images -> `ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1/255)`
- Batch Size of 1 (You may want to increase that)
- MNIST is grayscale pictures , therefore `color_mode` should be `"grayscale"`.

(Also you have several unused part in your code, that you may want to delete from the question)

Answer (score 0):

Adding two more point in answer of @abcdaire,

1. `mnist` has image size of `(28,28)`, you have assigned it wrong.
2. `Binarization` is another method, which can be used. It also make network to learn fast. It can be done like this.

`

```
imges_dataset = imges_dataset/255.0
imges_dataset = np.where(imges_dataset>0.5,1,0)
```